# Update on Duplicate key with two columns to check mysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql-insert, primary-key, create-table

I am trying to get my head around the 'On Duplicate Key' mysql statement. I have the following table:
id (primary key autoincr) / server id (INT) / member id (INT UNIQUE KEY) / basket (VARCHAR) / shop (VARCHAR UNIQUE KEY)

In this table each member can have two rows, one for each of the shops (shopA and shopB). I want to INSERT if there is no match for both the member id and shop. If there is a match I want it to update the basket to concat the current basket with additional information.

I am trying to use:
`"INSERT INTO table_name (server_id, member_id, basket, shop) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE basket = CONCAT (basket,%s)"`

Currently if there is an entry for the member for shopA when this runs with basket for shopB it adds the basket info to the shopA row instead of creating a new one.

Hope all this makes sense! Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: As requested here is the create table sql statement:
`CREATE TABLE table_name ( member_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, server_id bigint(11) NOT NULL, basket varchar(10000) NOT NULL, shop varchar(30) NOT NULL, notes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (member_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4`

Comment: As you explained the requirement neither member_id nor shop should be unique. Both of them combined should be unique. Post the CREATE TABLE statement of the table.

Comment: CREATE TABLE `table_name` (
 `member_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
 `server_id` bigint(11) NOT NULL,
 `basket` varchar(10000) NOT NULL,
 `shop` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`member_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this table each member can have two rows, one for each of the shops
> (shopA and shopB)

This means that `member_id` should **not** be the primary key of the table because it is not unique.
You need a composite primary key for the columns `member_id` and `shop`:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( 
  member_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
  server_id bigint(11) NOT NULL, 
  basket varchar(10000) NOT NULL, 
  shop varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
  notes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (member_id, shop) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

See a simplified [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9be86c30272b86849b1a3cf9b208e09d).